# Creating a loop to add a td

Tags: javascript, rows

I'm just learning javascript and trying to make a simple loop.

Here is a part of my code:

```
function addRow () {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    row.setAttribute("id", "sumrow");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode("toimii");
    row.appendChild(textNode);
    row.appendChild(td);
    td.appendChild(textNode);
    var table = document.getElementById("pricetable");
    table.appendChild(row);
```

Then it continues like this and I would like this code to be executed for 5 times:

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(row);
```

I would be very greatful if someone could help me. I have already tried to look for previous questions but I just don't get how I should apply them to my code.

Comment: Why you don't use for loop?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how.. Just trying to learn it

Comment: For documentation on how javascript things work, I tend to lean on W3Schools and MDN as good reference documentation. For the particular issue of loops, I've linked the following. For a known, fixed number of iterations (repetitions of the loop) a "for" loop is a common choice.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ) { your code here}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a loop you can use the following code (a for loop):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // in there you put the code you want to loop
}
```

The first part sets the variable `i` at 0

The next part says as long as `i` is `<`  (less than) 5

The final part says increase `i` by 1 each time

[More info on for loops here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: Thanks, now i got it!

Answer (score 0):

See the below code snippet. It using all your code which you have already written, might be easy for you to learn

```js
function addRow () {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    row.setAttribute("id", "sumrow");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode("toimii");
    row.appendChild(td);
    td.appendChild(textNode);
    return row;
}

function createRow() {
for(var i=0; i< 5; i++){
 var table = document.getElementById("pricetable");
    table.appendChild(addRow());
}
}
createRow();
```

```html
<table id="pricetable">
</table>
```